# ERR A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/home/vcap/app'

Tags: asp.net-core

After uploading my .NetCore Application in swisscom cloud, I tried to start the Application. It creashed with the Error in Title. 
What is to do, can anybody help?
Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough detail here to know what went wrong. Try adding more information to your questions. What steps did you take to produce this application? E.g. dotnet commands you ran, contents of your csproj file, which files did you upload. Other info that is helpful: which version of dotnet are you using and how did you install it.

Comment: Well, sorry. What I can see is the following:

Comment: Well, sorry. I have an API. I published it and uploaded to swisscom cloud. When I try to start it, it crashes.
Log:
Creating container
Successfully created container
Starting health monitoring of container
 ERR A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/home/vcap/app'. 
Exit status 131 
Exit status 0
Destroying container
Process has crashed with type: "web"
App instance exited with guid "" payload: {"reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"Exited with status 131; cancelled; ", "crash_count"=>12,